# How to display a string array to a JPanel?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, swing, jpanel

I have a string array that I want to display to a JPanel. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 4):

I would display your list using a `JList`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for working examples that show how to add data to the `ListModel` of the `JList`.

Basically instead of adding the strings to a `List` you add them to a `DefaultListModel` and add the model to the `JList`.

Comment: @Sharku, thanks, For some reason I was linking to an image, instead of the tutorial.